# Round off & Shorten money amount in T-SQL

Tags: t-sql

My stored proc returns some amounts (money) that I need to shorten, by rounding it off.
Amounts will be in Millions & Billions only.

For example,

```
$34,866,676.67 will be $35M
$34,366,676.67 will be $34M
$634,666,676.67 will be $635M
$7,634,666,676.67 will be $8B
$67,334,666,676.67 will be $67B
```

How can I achieve this? I'm using SQL Server 2014.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I just figured this out. 
If anyone interested, please check this code:

```
DECLARE @m MONEY; SET @m = 7362095.45
DECLARE @l TINYINT, @digit TINYINT;

SET @l = LEN(CAST(@m AS BIGINT))
SET @digit = IIF((@l % 3)=0, 3, (@l % 3));

SELECT '$' + LEFT(CAST(ROUND(@m, ((@l - @digit) * -1)) AS VARCHAR(16)), @digit) + IIF(@l > 9, 'B', 'M') /* Amount will be either in M or B */
```